# how to create optimize gridview in jsp

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, jsp-tags

I am creating a grid.

The problem with this grid is logic of count. The row logic is fine but i m getting extra columns.

My grid is of `n*3` where row will be depends on list size. If the total count is not multiple of 3 it creates blank column.

The loop which I'm using is:

```
<c:forEach var="showExistingProjectMap" items="${showExistingProjectList}" begin="0" end="${shareSpaseListSize}" step="3">
```

Please suggest the solution.